# How to trigger <a>'s click event on safari

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari

http://nycweb.io/test.html

Its html is

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" style="display:block">click</a>
```

In chrome's console, if you do

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click()
```

It will open a new page of google.com. Surprisingly, in Safari, this doesn't work. I searched around and found [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) saying there is a bug with Mobile Safari which prevents the `click` event from being triggered. Also it lists some workarounds. I was hoping it would help when I started reading it, but it actually makes me more confused.

First of all, it says the bug only happens with Mobile Safari, but anyone with a Macbook can test from the link above that it doesn't work with Safari either; second of all, it says it only happens with "elements that aren't typically interative", and the workaround includes adding "href" to `<a>` to make it interative. But my test above shows that it doesn't work with `<a>` at all, no matter it has `href` or not.

The actual problem I am trying to solve is this page "http://fbnydob.applinzi.com/test.php", where you can see a warning message pushed by the Hosting company, which can only be prevented by click the little 'x'. I was trying to click it programmatically but it is an `<a>` even without `href`, so my program fails to work on Apple devices and my users keep seeing this unpleasant message.

Any workaround for this that actually works?

Comment: Linked page does not appear available

Answer (score 0):

Could you try firing the click event?
   document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].fire('click')
This will call the click handler and close the popup window.